# If condition in batch files

Tags: windows, batch-file

```
@echo off
SET var1="Yes"
SET var2="No"
SET var3="Yes"
if %var1%=="Yes"
    echo Var1 set
if %var2%=="Yes"
    echo Var2 set
if %var3%=="Yes"
    echo Var3 set
```

If I run the above script I get the following error. Can anyone pls help?

> The syntax of the command is
>   incorrect.

Thanks.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The echo needs to either be at the end of the if statement:

```
if %var1%=="Yes" echo Var1 set
```

or of the following form:

```
if %var1%=="Yes" (
    echo Var1 set
)
```

I tend to use the former for very simple conditionals and the latter for multi-command ones and primitive `while` statements:

```
:while1
    if %var1%=="Yes" (
        :: Do something that potentially changes var1
        goto :while1
    )
```

What your particular piece of code is doing is trying to execute the command `if %var1%=="Yes"` which is not valid in and of itself.

Comment: Thanks. Is it applicable only for echo or for all the commands which follow as a positive result for if statement?

Comment: @bdhar, that's the syntax for the 'if' command so, yes, all of them, not just echo.

Answer (score 9):

You can't put a newline like that in the middle of the `IF`.  So you could do this:

```
if %var1%=="Yes" echo Var1 set
```

Or, if you do want your statements spread over multiple lines you can use brackets:

```
if %var1%=="Yes" (
   echo Var1 set
)
```

However, when you're using brackets be careful, because variable expansion might not behave as you expect.  For example:

```
set myvar=orange

if 1==1 (
   set myvar=apple
   echo %myvar%
)
```

Outputs:

```
orange
```

This is because everything between the brackets is treated as a single statement and all variables are expanded before any of the command between the brackets are run.  You can work around this using delayed expansion:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set myvar=orange

if 1==1 (
   set myvar=apple
   echo !myvar!
)
```

Comment: Sage advice. ALL my cmd scripts begin with 'setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion' (and end with 'endlocal').

Answer (score 3):

Take a look on IF command help:

```
C:\Users\Rubens>if /?
Performs conditional processing in batch programs.

IF [NOT] ERRORLEVEL number command
IF [NOT] string1==string2 command
IF [NOT] EXIST filename command
```

So, you command must be in same IF line. Your script should be:

```
@echo off
SET var1="Yes"
SET var2="No"
SET var3="Yes"
if %var1%=="Yes" echo Var1 set
if %var2%=="Yes" echo Var2 set
if %var3%=="Yes" echo Var3 set
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set var1=1
set var2=2
set var3=1

if "!var1!" == "1" echo Var1 set
if "!var2!" == "1" echo Var2 set
if "!var3!" == "1" echo Var3 set
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

Line-breaking is **forbidden** by the rules of syntax applicable in a command line script.

The command must instead be written to comply with the rules for splitting long commands into multiple lines -

```
if %var1%=="Yes"^
    echo Var1 set
```

In other words a caret (^) must be included, to tell the CMD program not to process the End Of Line flag.